# Validate text field in table view xcode

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

i am new in xcode.
In my project i am using table view that has multiple textfields.
How to get field value from table view and also how to validate.

Please help me
I am in trouble. I need to finish it asap

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out how to set the delegate for the text fields to be some object (probably your view controller) and then you can get the value at the same time you do validation.

You probably want to do validation when the user finishes typing into (or "editing") the text field, so make sure the object that handles the text field delegate method has it's own implementation of this method:  [`textFieldShouldEndEditing:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldEndEditing%3a) (presumably returning "`NO`" if the text field fails whatever you want to validate).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Suppose i have four text field in table view . User should enter all text fields . if they miss any of the field empty then there i need to validate fields .